# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: while using vs code to run c/c++

Tags: gcc, apple-m1

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_main", referenced from:
>          implicit entry/start for main executable
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is the error shown, I'm a beginner in C and C++ programming and I don't know what to do I have installed gcc successfully through homebrew and when I run this simple code for printing *Hello world* in VS code, it is showing this error. I don't know what I should do at this point.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    puts("Hello world\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code example that does get linked successfully?

Comment: Hi Abhi -- not quite sure how you might have gotten here, but ... you seem to be compiling using an arm compiler and trying to link against intel libs.  Simple programs should all work on M1, if everything is consistent (not so much if you need to link older libs).  In any case, be sure that brew is the m1 version, and that you installed gcc using that arm version of brew.  `which brew` and `brew --prefix gcc` should both show `/opt/homebrew/...` ... is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the problem had been solved already. I just encountered this problem yet my homebrew is installed at the right place, and I solved it by typing g++ instead of gcc. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29906802)